# Can I ask a partial duplicate? (Buried in the middle of a Bob Question)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

The question I'm considering asking is: Can I see (while debugging) the full SQL that will be sent to the server for my parameterized query (after all the parameters have been escaped, substituted, etc)?

It looks like another user was also curious about this, but that wasn't the only thing they were asking about:

[Where to insert code for Gridview UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37061202/1739000)

I **don't** want to ask a duplicate question. Would it be OK for me to ask a canonical question (not related to a specific debugging problem) for how to get this, or is that an incorrect way of thinking about it, or is it a duplicate of the above or another question?

Comment: Not Meta: If you use SQL Server, simple use SQL Server Profiler. I am sure there are other profilers for other RDBMS. That said, I am sure there already exists a canonical question. If nothing exists, create one.

Comment: This seems a little bit like, what you are searching (but of course can be improved to make it a better canonical): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390891/how-to-debug-parameterized-sql-query

Comment: Note that we can't mark your question as a duplicate of an unanswered question that isn't yours (and if you can ask it more clear and more specific, feel free to re-ask an unanswered question, as long as you didn't ask it in the first place and editing the old one will conflict with the interests of the original author). We can mark it as a duplicate of the one Christian referred to, though.

Comment: FYI, you have a misunderstanding of how SQL parameterization works. The parameters are not escaped and substituted. The SQL is first parsed, planned, and only *then* are parameters filled in. The SQL text as you sent it except with variables replaced never exists anywhere. That fundamental difference is why SQL parameterization is fool proof against any input, while escaping is not.

Comment: What is a *"Bob Question"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen a question written by Bob, I guess.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The question OP links to was asked by Bob, though I've got no idea why it was important enough to mention in this post title!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, **thank you so much** for looking for existing questions thoroughly before asking it. We need more people doing that!

Your question is not a duplicate. The linked question does not appear to have been narrowed down to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for starters. Furthermore, yours doesn't involve grid views or any particular UI elements or listening on any events. It's possible that the problem in the linked question is completely unrelated to SQL.

So yes, you may post a new question that is more clear and focused on a single issue when there's not an existing question that's more directly about your issue. *However*, please check if [From .NET can I get the full SQL string generated by a SqlCommand object (with SQL Parameters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5356467/1394393) is a duplicate of yours first. If not, then consider posting.

Regarding making a canonical question, I don't believe questions are usually made canonical unilaterally by the asker. But that's not really a problem. Don't worry about whether the question is canonical or not. If you have a question that applies to a wide variety of situations, just ask it and write it well.

Comment: That was the dupe I was looking for, thanks.  Too bad it had weird tags so didn't show up in my "[sql] parameterized" search.

Comment: @NH. Google is your best friend when looking for dupes: https://www.google.com/search?q=ado.net+view+full+sql+with+parameters+subtituted. The SO Search is well known to be very poor.

Comment: Or, on second thought... I think that one is a dupe of the one Christian linked me to (https://stackoverflow.com/q/390891/1739000). I gave it a dupe flag. Now I see why you say we need more people looking for dupes first.

Comment: @NH. Debatable. The one that Christian linked doesn't seem to emphasize performing the substitution. So hard to say. Sometimes it's not clear cut. ;)

Comment: Actually, that's the point.  SQL doesn't perform the substitution, or at least not in the way I thought it did.